# Vue 3 composition api typescript fill object properties from route query

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I wanna fill my object properties automatically from route query, but I have typescript error, This is my code:

```
 const initialFilter = {
      page: 1,
      search: '',
      min_date: '',
      max_date: '',
      min_price: '',
      max_price: '',
    };
    const filter = ref<ExpenseFilterType>(initialFilter);

 Object.entries(route.query).forEach((query) => {
      filter.value[query[0]] = query[0] === 'page' ? parseInt(query[1] as string) : query[1];
    });
```

And error:
[image]

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Object.entries(route.query).forEach((query) => {
      filter.value[query[0]] =
        query[0] === 'page'
          ? parseInt(query[1] as string)
          : (query[1] as string);
    });
```